# MySQL Query Count two Fields

Tags: mysql

I have a database table (notes) that has three columns: id, ticket, and user.

I need to show how many notes were entered by each user as well as how many unique tickets those notes were added to (grouped by user). For example, John Doe entered 100 notes into 50 unique tickets and Jane Doe entered 70 notes into 65 unique tickets. I'm not interested in which tickets they were added to, just how many.

Here is what I have so far.

```
select count(id) count
from notes
group by user
```

Is it possible to grab the number of unique tickets in the same query?

Comment: try to use distinct keyword :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` inside the count:

```
select
  user,
  count(id) note_count,
  count(distinct ticket) ticket_count
from notes
group by user
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably new to SQL.  The query is something like:

```
select user, count(distinct TicketId) as NumTickets, count(id) as NumNotes
from notes
group by user
```

You should include the user in the `select` clause, so you know to whom the numbers apply.  When naming things, it is a good idea to avoid reserved words like `count`, so I named on `NumTickets` and the other `NumNotes`.